# Polling server serving multiple users requests

Tags: node.js, socket.io, queue, polling

I need to serve the data I'm getting from an external API to multiple users requests. I was wondering what is the strategie to use in that case.

For example :

- User 1 sends request for data "A" => Server start polling responses with data "A"
- User 2 sends request for data "A" => Server start polling responses with data "A"
- User 3 sends request for data "B" => Server start polling responses with data "B"

Then for the server side :

- Received request for data "A" from User 1 => Check if data "A" is already polled :

  - If yes : Start polling data "A"
  - If no : Start polling data "A" from external API and start polling to User 1
- Received request for data "A" from User 2 => Check if data "A" is already polled :

  - If yes : Start polling data "A"
  - If no : Start polling data "A" from external API and start polling to User 2
- Received request for data "B" from User 3 => Check if data "B" is already polled :

  - If yes : Start polling data "B"
  - If no : Start polling data "A" from external API and start polling to User 3

Of course what I would like to do is that since User1 and User2 requests the same data, the server will no make twice the request to the API. I don't know how to do that.

Also, the requests to the API have to be polled for ie every 10 or 30 sec when a user made a request and at least one user is still connected.

About the technologie, I will have to do it with NodeJS. Then I was thinking of doing all this through a socket.io instead of ajax calls.

Please could someone explain me a system that can do that in Node ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the server to cache `A` so that if another user requests it, the server can quickly send `A` stored in memory.

The Node.js code would be this:

```
var cachedData;

socket.on('requestDataA',function(data){
    var date = new Date().getTime();
    //check and see if cachedData is expired

    if(data >=cachedData.expireDate){
        cachedData=null;
    }

    if(!cachedData){
        pollServerToGetA(function(A){
            cachedData=A;
            socket.emit('dataA',cachedData);
        });
    }else{
        socket.emit('dataA',cacheData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a small test and it serves the cached data for the others users. But I made all this without the date/expireDate thing. Could you explain me about it ? Does that mean I have to set a caching expiration ? If ie I poll every 30sec then my cache should expire every 45sec maybe ?

Comment: @BobbyShark I'm just assuming that `A` will change every so often, and after a certain amount of time, `A` will need to be refreshed so that users always get the latest data, and not an old copy. A date when `A` will expire would be the `expireDate`. If `date` is past the `expireDate` this means the content should be pulled from the server. You should poll the server as infrequently as possible, while still assuring that you're getting the latest version of `A`